# Perl Regular Expression is being ignored?

Tags: regex, perl

Sorry if this isn't Stack Overflow worthy but I'm stumped. Here is my code:

```
#Search tmpData for a <whack> tag and replace with REPLACEMENTSTRING (this works)
$tmpData =~ s/<\s*whack\s+([^\/>]*)(\/?>)/"$REPLACEMENTSTRING"/i;

if($defaultData ne '') {
print "pre $1 And $2... '$&'\n";

#Search for data inside <whack> tag and closing tag </whack> and remove them.
$tmpData =~ s/$defaultData<\/whack>$//;
print "FOUND $1 And $2... '$&'\n";
```

For those not aware, `$&` shows the regex match. The problem is that the second regular expression appears to not be executing at all: the last print statement shows all the values from the first regular expression. You would expect `$&` would modify here. Right?

My test data is: `$tmpData is: yo "WHACKREPLACEMENT-idname2"helloworld</whack>`

after the first regular expression.
`$defaultData is: helloworld`

I tried pulling this code out from the main script into a test file that isn't strict and it worked :(

What is going on?! Thanks!

**EDIT**
I wasn't sure how to make this clearer so I thought I would post the output from my debugger at the point of error:

main::(c:\exec\webwhack.pl:109): *$tmpData =~ s/$defaultData</whack>$//;*

DB<2> **p $tmpData, $defaultData**

**"WHACKATAG2837293REPLACEMENT-idname2"removeMe**

**removeMe**

DB<3> n

main::(c:\exec\webwhack.pl:110):        print "FOUND $1 And $2... '$&'\n";

DB<3> **p $tmpData, $defaultData**

**"WHACKATAG2837293REPLACEMENT-idname2"removeMe**

**removeMe**

So you can see that going into the regular expression "removeMe" exists at the end of the string. Coming out of the regular expression though- it's as if nothing changed. :(

**EDIT2**

I should also point out that all these statements are wrapped in a:

```
while( $tmpData =~ m/<\s*whack\s+([^\/>]*)(\/?>)/ig) { ... }
```

loop

Comment: When posting please consider posting something reproducible. We are not gods and cannot know what your variables contain.

Comment: It seems there has been made some subtle changes to the question after I posted my answer, which makes it invalid. I suggest you post the whole relevant code instead of parts of it with your interpretations of what's going on attached. It's not possible to provide any meaningful help as of now.

Comment: Hey guys, I have not made any "subtle changes" to the question... what are you talking about?

My apologies for not making this more detailed- I will begin looking it over and seeing how I can clarify it.

Comment: Then I apologize. The revisions don't make anything any clearer though. You should include your variable initializations in your code. As it is, the code you've posted isn't even valid without strict and warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say exactly with no values for `$defaultData` and `$tmpData`, but that would be what you see when your `$defaultData` pattern isn't being matched in the second `=~`.

After all, [man perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions) says:

> $&      The string matched by the last **successful** pattern match

I'd structure it like this:

```
#Search tmpData for a <whack> tag and replace with REPLACEMENTSTRING (this works)
$tmpData =~ s/<\s*whack\s+([^\/>]*)(\/?>)/"$REPLACEMENTSTRING"/i;

if($defaultData ne '') {
  print "pre $1 And $2... '$&'\n";

  #Search for data inside <whack> tag and closing tag </whack> and remove them.
  if($tmpData =~ s/$defaultData<\/whack>$//) { 
    print "FOUND $1 And $2... '$&'\n";  
  } else { 
    print "NOT FOUND";
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your first substitute operation is changing $tmpData such that the second substitute pattern is not matching.

That said, I think you could simplify your code with a single substitute operation if you're just trying to grab what's inside your whack tage like this:

```
if ($tmpdata =~ s/<whack>(.*?)<\/whack>/$1/) {

    print "Found whack tag value: $tmpdata\n";
}
```

Update: fixed the slash

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably go this route... but first, I want to figure out what is going wrong!

Comment: I would try printing $tmpdata to the console to debug it.  I always use single quotes in the output in case there are whitespace characters on the ends:  print "'$tmpdata'\n";

Answer (score 1):

Why would the second regular expression execute? **yo "WHACKREPLACEMENT-idname2"helloworld** doesn't end with `</whack>`. Remember that $1, $2 and $& contains the values from the last **successful** match, which in your case is the first regexp.

The reason why `$1`, `$2`, `$&` and `$tmpData` don't change is that your second regexp doesn't match anything in `$tmpData`. If you had modified your code to show the relevant code, so that we could see what's going on, it would be easy to point out exactly why. Instead you've posted more irrelevant info.

Let me show you how easy it is to post code where it's clear what's going on:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $defaultData = "yo";
my $tmpData = "$defaultdata <whack id='IcedDante'>helloworld</whack>";
my $REPLACEMENTSTRING = "WHACKREPLACEMENT-idname";

#Search tmpData for a <whack> tag and replace with REPLACEMENTSTRING (this works)

$tmpData =~ s/<\s*whack\s+([^\/>]*)(\/?>)/"$REPLACEMENTSTRING"/i;

if($defaultData ne '') {
    print "pre $1 And $2... '$&'\n";

    #Search for data inside <whack> tag and closing tag </whack> and remove them.
    $tmpData =~ s/$defaultData<\/whack>$//;
    print "FOUND $1 And $2... '$&'\n";  
}
```

(I tried to reconstruct your code from the information you've given us, but it was impossible.)

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. I guess I just saw two up-votes and your answer was incorrect for my situation. Not that it was your fault, it was totally mine for not being clear enough, but defaultData in this case was the innerText of the <whack /> tag.

I really do appreciate you taking the time to provide an answer and hope that my downvote doesn't damage your rep.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, the problem was that I didn't chomp my file input line and $defaultData had a '\n' character at the end of the regular expression as a result.

To save this from becoming a total disaster I'll explain what I did in the hope that it will help someone else in the future. The error in logic occurred before this code was even reached. I was attempting to extract the data between the opening and closing "whack" tag:

```
<whack>Extract this data.</whack>
```

Using this code:

```
$defaultData = substr $tmpData, pos($tmpData);
$defaultData =~ s/(.+)<\/whack>/$1/;
```

I didn't realize that this code would extract all the text before "", and *everything after the tag on that line as well*. In this case, that was a newline. I replaced the regular expression with:

```
$defaultData =~ s/(.+)<\/whack>.*/$1/;
```

Of course, this would be impossible to determine based on what I provided in the original question and I will attempt to do a better job in the future.